# Can I get the properties of the color of a Microsoft Excel cell in numbers/text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, cells

I want to count the yellow, red and white (no color) cells in a column (range) within a Microsoft Excell sheet.
The colors are equal (i.e. only one RGB value of yellow is used, not light/dark yellow etc).

Is this possible?

Comment: By white you mean the background color white or "no background color"?

Comment: did you take a look at this? http://superuser.com/q/328326/14596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a way with normal Excel functions.
But here is a quick solution using [VBA](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications).

- open your workbook and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- insert the code below into *sheet1* or where ever your data is
- customize the `Range("A1:A100")` to whatever you need
- close the VBA editor and go back to the sheet with your data
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and execute the macro

  ```
  Sub countcolor()
  For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
      Select Case cell.Interior.ColorIndex
      Case 6: yellow = yellow + 1
      Case 3: red = red + 1
      Case 2: white = white + 1
      Case Else: others = others + 1
      End Select
  Next
  MsgBox "Yellow: " & yellow & Chr(13) _
       & "Red: " & red & Chr(13) _
       & "White: " & white & Chr(13) _
       & "Others: " & others
  End Sub
  ```